# What are the units of CASpringAnimation's initialVelocity?

Tags: ios, core-animation

What are the units of `CASpringAnimation`'s `initialVelocity` property? I thought it could be:

- points per second or
- `abs(fromValue - toValue)` per second

but neither seems to be the case (I could be wrong though).

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, it is indeed total animation distance per second. This corresponds to the `initialSpringVelocity` argument in a similar method (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622594-animate):

> A value of 1 corresponds to the total animation distance traversed in
>   one second. For example, if the total animation distance is 200 points
>   and you want the start of the animation to match a view velocity of
>   100 pt/s, use a value of 0.5.